# Collecting 3 years of data and building a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am collecting 3 years of data and building a string that will be used with an ASP Literal control. The method `GetListOfMeetingBygroupId` takes in a `groupID` and `year` and will return meeting for that group and year.

```
    MeetingService ms = new MeetingService();
    int groupId = 574;

    //Meeting

    int totalYearCount = 3;
    StringBuilder sbMeeting = new StringBuilder();
    DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;
    for (int x = 1; x <= totalYearCount; x++)
    {

        var list = ms.GetListOfMeetingBygroupId(groupId, aDate.Year);

        sbMeeting.AppendFormat("<p><b>{0}</p></b>",aDate.ToString("yyyy"));

        foreach (var meeting in list)
        {
                sbMeeting.Append("<p>");

                DateTime meetingendDate = Convert.ToDateTime(meeting.MeetingDateList.Select(c => c.StartDate).Max());
                DateTime meetingstartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(meeting.MeetingDateList.Select(c => c.StartDate).Min());

                int totalMeetingPresentation = ms.GetListOfPresentationsBymeetingId(meeting.MeetingId).Count();

                sbMeeting.Append(meetingstartDate.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd  yyyy"));
                sbMeeting.Append("<br>");
                sbMeeting.Append(meeting.Type.Name);
                sbMeeting.Append("<br>");

                if (totalMeetingPresentation > 0)
                { 
                    sbMeeting.AppendFormat("<a class='body'href=meetingdetails.aspx?meetingId={0}>{1}</a>", meeting.MeetingId, "Minutes and Presentations");
                }
                else
                {

                    var meetingMinFile = ms.GetMeetingFile(meeting.MeetingId);
                    sbMeeting.AppendFormat("<td><a href=../../../Common/FileManager.ashx?FileManagerId={0}>{1}</a></td>", meetingMinFile.FileManagerId, "Minutes");

                }
                sbMeeting.Append("<p>");
                sbMeeting.Append("<br>");
                sbMeeting.Append("</p>");
       }
        aDate = aDate.AddYears(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested the output of this code? I can see multiple broken HTML tags in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll focus on the C# part of the code, but please run the output HTML through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) because at first glance I count no fewer than five HTML tags that are mismatched, misplaced, or simply broken.

## Outer loop

You're not using the loop variable `x` anywhere. This suggests that the loop should be refactored around the thing that you're *actually* iterating over, which seems to be a *range of years*.

Each year is just an integer; you can get a range of integers using `Enumerable.Range`. You want the most recent `totalYearCount` years (inclusive of this year), so start the range at `nowYear - totalYearCount + 1`. You want this year *first*, so reverse the sequence too.

```
foreach (var year in Enumerable
    .Range(aDate.Year - totalYearCount + 1, totalYearCount)
    .Reverse())
{
    var list = ms.GetListOfMeetingBygroupId(groupId, year);
    // ...
}
```

You can replace `aDate.ToString("yyyy")` accordingly.

## Naming

When using `camelCase` and `PascalCase`, each distinct word should start with a capital letter. `GetListOfMeetingByGroupId`, `GetListOfPresentationsByMeetingId`, `meetingStartDate`, `meetingEndDate`, and so on.

Type prefixes like `sb` don't help much, especially when abbreviated. Rename that variable to better reflect what it actually is: it's a builder for the output, so maybe `outputBuilder` instead of `sbMeeting`.

`list` is a really generic name for something we know to be a collection of meetings, so call it `meetings` or `meetingList`.

## Code we haven't seen

It's advised to post or link to all supporting code. It's at least relevant because of this here:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(meeting.MeetingDateList.Select(c => c.StartDate).Max());
```

What's the type of `c.StartDate`? You're converting it to a `DateTime` *after getting the maximum date* -- so it's probably not a `DateTime` already -- which begs the question *how are you sorting the dates*? I suspect you might've wanted the order switched:

```
meeting.MeetingDateList.Max(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c.StartDate));
```

Note that I've used the overload for `Max` that takes a selector so that I can avoid the unnecessary `Select`.

## General readability

Your spacing is inconsistent. Consistent spacing would make for better readability, so I offer these suggestions:

- Use exactly one indent per `{}` block -- your inner `foreach` loop is double-indented.
- Avoid empty lines of padding within `{}` blocks -- see your `for` loop and the `else` block.
- Parameters should be separated by a comma and one space -- see your first `sbMeeting.AppendFormat(...)`.

All of those hard-coded HTML strings should be refactored out into some kind of template. They have no business being encoded inline in the method like that.

Comment: What do you mean template?

Answer (score 2):

These lines look nice and readable

```
   sbMeeting.Append("<p>");
   sbMeeting.Append("<br>");
   sbMeeting.Append("</p>");
```

but if you want to have a little more performance, just use one string.

```
   sbMeeting.Append("<p><br></p>");
```